# Select a radio button and display the value of the row selected in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

When I click on the status radio button, I should display the whole row below this table below.

The purpose of creating another table is I'm trying to edit the code in the second data table. Note that there are multiple rows and multiple radio buttons, if I select any of the radio buttons I should be able to display the corresponding row in a separate table and save.

Can you please assist me in displaying the table and, then I can work on the save part?

```
<div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 450px; width: 420px;">
  <table class="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th width="120" align="center" colspan="2">Status</th>
      <th width="130" align="center">Name</th>
      <th width="50" align="center">Code</th>
      <th width="50" align="center">level</th>
      <th width="120" align="center">Date</th>
    </tr>

    <%
      int index = 1;
    %>

    <c:forEach items="${List.Rates}" var="state">
      <tr id="rateRow1<%=index%>">      
      <td align="center"><input id="dummyRadio<%=index%>" name="<%=index%>" type="radio"/></td>
      <td align="left" id="rateAdjType<%=index%>" title="<c:out value="${state.key.Status}"/>"><c:out value="${state.key.Status}"/></td>        
      <td><c:out value="${state.Name}"/></td>   
      <td><c:out value="${state.Code}"/></td>   
      <td><c:out value="${state.level}"/></td>  
      <td><c:out value="${state.date}"/></td>                   
      </tr>         
    </c:forEach>
```

[image: table row]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class name to each `td` and add a new class to radio button example:

```
<c:forEach items="${List.Rates}" var="state">
  <tr id="rateRow1<%=index%>">        
    <td align="center"><input id="dummyRadio<%=index%>" class="class_radio" name="<%=index%>" type="radio"/></td>
    <td align="left" id="rateAdjType<%=index%>" title="<c:out value="${state.key.Status}"/>"><c:out value="${state.key.Status}"/></td>      
    <td class="class_name"><c:out value="${state.Name}"/></td> 
    <td class="class_code"><c:out value="${state.Code}"/></td> 
    <td class="class_level"><c:out value="${state.level}"/></td>    
    <td class="class_date"><c:out value="${state.date}"/></td>                 
  </tr>           
</c:forEach>
```

Later you can get each `td` value as following:

```
$(".classradio").change(function(){
  var name = $(this).parent().find(".class_name").val();
  var code = $(this).parent().find(".class_code").val();
})
```